# Download source for Subsonic 2.2

Tags: subsonic

Is there a place where I can get the source code for Subsonic 2.2?  The closest I can find is subsonic 2.1.1.  I have the Subsonic 2.2 .dll, but need the source code, for policy purposes....Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

SubSonic 2's hosted on github. You can find it [here](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0)

Comment: Also, just to note. The Github folder name is 2.0, but it actually contains 2.2.1.0. You can check the SubSonic/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs for release number.

Comment: Thanks. But If I download the .zip file from github, the assembly files all say 2.1.1.0.  Do I need download each file separately?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to generate source code from a .NET assembly, although grabbing the latest source from [github](http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0) is probably the better solution.